# Outlook 2013 adds unwanted padding to cells

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have a problem which I'm trying to resolve for a week now but with no success so far. I have an email build from sliced images. The probem is that in Outlook 2013 there is space between them in which the td background color is shown. Like some kind of padding is added in Outlook. I can't figure it out, also in my Outlook 2013 email looks fine, but in two Outlooks at my clients company problem appears.

The problem looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnXMx.jpg

There should not be green space between images and on the right side. The problem only exist in Outlook 2013.

This is my code for this part of the email:
http://pastebin.com/xFbnitzj

There is of course href, title and alt marks filled in full code.

I will be very thankful for any tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Different emails provider have different restrictions for data-transfer. In this case, Microsoft's mail cannot use the `padding` style. For the complete CSS support please see:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thanks for replay Daniel. The thing is I've just added padding and margin to the code hoping that this will resolve it. The problem still exist without padding and margin in the code.

Comment: Unfortunately problem still exist without a padding in the code so I'm still looking for solution.

Comment: there is no actual solution if the email provider doesn't allow a CSS style to be executed, because it would mess up the style of the interface. For your problem, you need to use `margin` instead of `padding`, maybe using js, but else, there is no solution in CSS.

Comment: But there is no CSS to execute, Outlook adds some space between content of the td cell and the border of this td. It looks like this:
td cell: ||image| - some space - border|
It adds padding where no padding is definied at all. :<

Comment: maybe it has a default padding? did you try inspect element?

Comment: I've inspected it in IE11 and Chrome and it looks ok, padding is 0 and margin also is 0.